# Kotlin, jackson: cannot annotate @JsonCreator in primary constructor

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I want to annotate with [`@JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) using a primary constructor, something like this:

```
// error
@JsonCreator class User(
    @JsonProperty("username") var username: String,
    @JsonProperty("password") var password: String
) {
  // ...
}
```

But the @JsonCreator annotation gives an error "This annotation is not applicable to target 'class'".

Using a secondary constructor works, but is it the only (or best) way?:

```
// works, but is there a better way?
class User @JsonCreator constructor(
    @JsonProperty("username") var username: String,
    @JsonProperty("password") var password: String
) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That's not a secondary constructor. It's the primary one. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors *If the primary constructor does not have any annotations or visibility modifiers, the constructor keyword can be omitted*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you describe here:

```
class User @JsonCreator constructor(
    @JsonProperty("username") var username: String,
    @JsonProperty("password") var password: String
) {
  // ...
}
```

is actually explicitly specifying the **primary** constructor. You can differentiate the *primary* from the *secondary* by looking at the class declaration:

```
class User constructor(/** **/) { // <-- primary

    constructor(/** ... **/) { // <-- secondary

    }

}
```

if the constructor is part of the class *header* it is a primary constructor, if it is part of the class declaration (it is after the `{`) it is a secondary one.